# vue-js-modal not showing in HTML

Tags: vue.js

I checked the [demo](https://github.com/euvl/vue-js-modal/blob/master/demo/src/components/Modal_Resizable.vue) and confirmed it does work in the demo way. But I need to use the components in HTML but not in webpack-ed a modal.vue template. So I wrote the following:

```html
<body>

        <div id="app">
            <modal name="test">
                test
            </modal>
        </div>

    <script src="{% static 'js/tmpdev.bundle.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
    <script>

    Vue.use(VueJsModal, {
        dialog: true,
        dynamicDefaults: {
            draggable: true
        }
    })

    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        components: {
        },
        data() {
            return {
            };
        },
        mounted() {
            window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
                if (e.key == 'Escape') {
                    this.toggle();
                }
            });
            this.$modal.show('test');
        },
        methods: {
            toggle() {
                this.$modal.show('test');
            }
        },
        filters: {
        },
    });

    </script>

</body>
```

The above should display the modal window on the screen immediately when I reloaded the tab or additionally when I pressed "esc" key. But for some reason this doesn't show the modal. The console log has no error on it, I can see `<div id="modals-container"></div>` on the HTML source, the `this.$modal.show('test');` part is executed without an error. So I have no clue now. What is wrong with the code above? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `Escape` key `EventListener` code in the created life cycle hook.

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', this.toggle);
```

In methods object **:**

```
toggle(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 27) {
    this.$modal.show('test');
    console.log('esc key pressed');
  }
}
```

Once you done with the requirement, You can destroy this event to prevent memory leaks.

```
destroyed: function() {
  document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.toggle);
}
```

Comment: But how do you explain the `mounted` `this.$modal.show('test');` also doesn't work?

Comment: What issue you are facing at which line of code ?

Comment: The `<modal name="test">
                test
            </modal>` should be shown when I fired `this.$modal.show('test');`, right? But the issue is that `this.$modal.show('test');` does nothing as if the `modal name="test"` is not exist in the #app.

Comment: You mean `this.$modal.show('test');` is not even triggering ? but as per your question you said it is showing on page load.

Comment: I think it's triggering when the page load and also when I press "esc". But it does nothing with displaying the element. From `I can see <div id="modals-container"></div> on the HTML source` I mean I opened up a chrome dev tool and inspected the source, and I can see the div. So just wanted to explain that at least `<modal name="test">
                test
            </modal>` looks working, but the problem is on the showing process for some reason.

Comment: Ok. You have to cross check that your `modal` element is injected properly or not. Ideally it should work as it is under div `app`